# Reuse WidgetProvider outside Home?

Tags: android, widget, host

I need the same functionality that my widget provides in another part of my application. Inside a list activity.  How could I reuse my widget in a custom view?  I would like to put the Widget unto a View?  How can this be done?  Building a custom host.  I mean I think I would need for whatever I build to be a broadcast receiver anyway, so how can I resuse the Widget provider Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I assume you mean "app widget" where you say "widget". There is a big difference between a widget (subclass of `android.view.View`) and an app widget.

> How could I reuse my widget in a custom view?

Generally, you don't. You isolate common business logic into some helper class that both your AppWidgetProvider and your ListActivity use.

> I would like to put the Widget unto a View? How can this be done?

That is not possible, sorry.

> Building a custom host.

You *so* don't want to go down that path. Building an `AppWidgetHost` should be reserved for home screens or other places where you are looking to host app widgets from third parties. Please, just refactor your business logic.

> I mean I think I would need for whatever I build to be a broadcast receiver anyway, so how can I resuse the Widget provider

A `ListActivity` would not use an `AppWidgetProvider`. Please, just refactor your business logic.